# Changing background image of HTML document from list of filenames using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, file, background

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and I was making a simple project. Basically I have an HTML document and I want to change the background image every time it is opened up to a random picture from a directory located at 'Background'.

```
function main()
{
    // Creates a list of filenames from the 'Background/' dir and gets a 
    // random index in the list
    var fs = require('fs');
    var fileList = fs.readdirSync('/Background/');
    var len = fileList.length;
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);

    var filePath = "Background/" + fileList[index];

    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(filePath)";
    document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover"
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

For whatever reason it doesn't seem to work. I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how the URL class works, because I think it has something to do with that. I'm not getting any errors. I got the background image to change to specific image when I did this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('Background/green.jpg')";
```

But not when I try and retrieve the filenames randomly.
I'm sure it's just a misunderstanding of the language or something but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure how you expect node to run in the browser....

Comment: To @epascarello 's point -- fs (or filesystem) is a Node.js (server-side) specific tool.  You'll need another way to capture the images' file names (manage a list, create a service, ...)

Comment: @Doug Oh interesting. Thanks for actually explaining the reason behind the error. Is there any specific tools or methods you recommend?

Comment: If the file names won't change often, the easiest route would be to create an array of the names and use Math.random() to select from that.  If you don't know how often or what the names will be (at a semi-reliable level) then you can use Node.js (or another server side language) to create a service that will return a random filename to you, based on what exists in your directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use fs in this way in browser. You need to store images paths. You can store them in database or in array in your javascript file. Below example with storing filenames in array.

```
function main()
{
    var images = ['image1.jpeg', 'image2.jpg', 'bg.png'] //storing only names
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)
    var filePath = "Background/" + images[index]; //creating full path
    document.body.style.background = 'url("'+filePath+'")'
    // if background-size is not changing, it's better to store it in .css file
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Also, if you want to store your filenames in database, you can load names into images array, so my code example will not change.

Comment: Thank you, however I was hoping to simply be able to drag new pictures into the folder if I needed to add any and have it still work. Hence the reason why I was trying to retrieve the file names rather than hard code them in. Would a database be able to solve this issue?

Comment: Maybe a bit late, sorry.
Anyway, to use database you will need a server app, to connect frontend with database. In server side you can make function which returns filepath. This function should:

 * create array of filenames in backgrounds directory

 * generate random number from 0 to filenames array - 1

 * get array element on generated in previosu step position

 * concat name with full path, so it's will be correct for src attribute

 * return full path to frontend